# Save state of recyclerview list

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I created a list using recyclerview in one activity. The user dynamically removes some of the items he/she doesn't from the list so the problem arises when he navigates back to that activity. The activity retrieves all the data items,including the ones he removed. How do i make sure the recyclerview list retains the state the user left it in?

Comment: What do you use to store your items? Is it SQLite or files or ArrayLIst?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in List you are using. You need to use Activity's list reference in Adapter too, Don't create different list in adapter just save Activity's list reference in Adapter.

Comment: okay, i followed your instruction but now I cannot assign the parceable arraylist from the saved instance in the onRestoreItemState method. I get an incomaptibe return type error. I used the getParcelableArrayList method

Comment: Use Bundle to save your array on onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) of activity

    http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.htmlUpdate
    How do I save an Android application's state?  @Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
  // Save UI state changes to the savedInstanceState.
  // This bundle will be passed to onCreate if the process is
  // killed and restarted.
    outState.putStringArrayList("Playlist", playerList );

   super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    }